# Expresion language code is show as plain text JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp

Im triying to execute some EL code on my tomcat app.

If I paste this same code in a new app (with the css, js, etc) it works, but when I paste it in the app that I need , it is showed as a plain text.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link
    href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link
    href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/style.css"
    rel="stylesheet">

<script
    src="assets/script/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script
    src="assets/script/bootstrap.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="page-content-wrapper" class="page-content-toggle">
        <div class="container-fluid">


            <div class="row">
                <div id="content" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-12">
 THIS IS PRINTED LIKE PLAIN TEXT----->  ${param.content}
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This should show a "table" but is printed like plain text. Why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: This `${param.content}` is not `Jquery` it is [EL(Expression Language)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) .

Comment: I thought that this was JQuery, sorry. But my teacher said that this should be shown like a table. What am I doing something wrong?

Comment: did you set values for `${param.content}` ?

Comment: @Swati Yes, I taken this code from an exercise from class and this is working, but when I imported all the files, libraries, etc inside the biggest project, is fails. Maybe could it be because the other proyect have the libraries in jar, and mine have in maven dependencies?

Comment: No , that is not an issue, try posting code where you have set value for `${param.content}` .

Comment: Let me search it (it have 4 JS too big hahah). Other thing that dont work is ${pageContext.request.contextPath}, if I try it to the <link> of this page, dont work (I changed it to plain url, but in the original code it's include it, and it should work without problems,no?)@Swati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
The problem was with the web.xml, I changed the version from 2.5 to 3.1. Changing the  tag to this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
```